# Provide both a global theme and enforce default styles on some controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, theming

I've applied the [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) theme to our application in the App.xaml. Using this mechanism to style the application's menu and dialogs works well, but our application also allows the user to create their own forms and customize properties for many of the WPF controls.

I need to ensure that that the global styles don't apply to any of these user-customized controls. There are only two UserControl elements in the application that may be composed of user-customized controls. To cancel the global theme I'm providing a resource dictionary of default styles in the UserControl.Resource section like so:

**UserCustomizableForm.xaml**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../DefaultWPFSyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Where DefaultWPFStyles.xaml is just a list of default styles for any control that we allow the user to customize:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Style TargetType="Border"/>
    <Style TargetType="Button"/>
    <Style TargetType="Canvas"/>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox"/>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox"/>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem"/>
...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I haven't devised another way to force all controls below a designated UserConrol to default styles carte-blanche. I'm hoping someone could suggest a way if I've overlooked it.

Comment: Does your way work? If it does, are you looking for different ways?

Comment: it appears to work. I'd prefer a solution that didn't require this xaml defaults file with dozens of default control style declarations - if there was such a solution.